# Low-rank matrix satisfying linear constraints linear mapping

Tags: optimization, linear-transformations, convex-optimization, nuclear-norm, matrix-completion

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be a matrix that is assumed to be low rank. According to,

- *Recht, Benjamin; Fazel, Maryam; Parrilo, Pablo A.*, [**Guaranteed minimum-rank solutions of linear matrix equations via nuclear norm minimization**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/070697835), SIAM Rev. 52, No. 3, 471-501 (2010). [ZBL1198.90321](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1198.90321).

if we have a set of linear equality constraints on the entries of matrix $X$, then we can solve the following convex optimization program to achieve our solution

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{X}{\text{minimize}}
& & \Vert X \Vert_* \\
& \text{subject to}
& & \mathcal{A}(X) = b
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where $\mathcal{A} :\mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \to \mathbb{R}^p$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^p$. I am confused how to express my linear equations in the form of this linear mapping $\mathcal{A}$. One way is to define a matrix $A^{(k)} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ with coefficients of $X_{ij}$ and other elements as $0$ in matrix $A^{(k)}$, then every constraint can be expressed as

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{A} = \langle A^{(k)}, X \rangle = \sum_{ij} A_{ij}X_{ij} = b_k \quad \forall k= 1, ..., p 
\end{equation}

Now, I am not sure how to define adjoint $\mathcal{A}^*$ because we need that to solve the problem using accelerated proximal gradient method according to the following paper.

- *Toh, Kim-Chuan; Yun, Sangwoon*, [**An accelerated proximal gradient algorithm for nuclear norm regularized linear least squares problems**](http://www.ybook.co.jp/online/pjoe/vol6/615.html), Pac. J. Optim. 6, No. 3, 615-640 (2010). [ZBL1205.90218](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1205.90218).

Is there any other way to define this mapping and its adjoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adjoint operator is simply a linear combination of the matrices $A^{(k)}$.  $A^{*}(y)=y_{1}A^{(1)}+\ldots +y_{p}A^{(p)}$

Comment: Thanks you so much!